# Should parents of young children set an example of socializing by using Facebook?

Tags: toddler, infant, social-media

If parents don't use Facebook, how will their children know how to use Facebook or other social media technology in healthy ways?

Should parents be utilizing these technologies so at least their children will have an example?

I'm talking about infants/toddlers, those who are new to life and technology.

Comment: This reads like a troll post. (If it's not, my apologies, but in that case I'd point out: If you want to teach your children how to socialize, stop using Facebook)

Comment: I saw this from StackOverflow and just had to sign in here... why in the world would you believe Facebook to be beneficial and necessary to anyone? Yeesh. The signal to noise ratio is horrible.  My advice; don't use FB at all and keep them away from such things as long as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Infants and toddlers don't yet have the information to understand normal, basic, face to face social interactions. They cannot understand the point of social media, publishing, and broadcasting. Lay the basics first, then layer on the advanced stuff.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it is necessary to use all the technology that your children are using to help them understand how to use it safely. There are way too many apps and other things that they can use and will use in the future for you to be able to use all of them and then teach them proper usage. I feel that if you explain basic concepts like don't give out information on where you live, don't meet up with someone you only know from online, don't spend more than an hour a day catching up with friends, etc. and why these guidelines are important, those same ideas will work in twitter, snapchat, instagram, and such without you needing to be on each one. I do suggest you learn one or 2 of these "social media" technology to see what happens and what might happen.

Once they know why certain behaviors are important they will better be able to decide on their own what they should and shouldn't do in most situations.

Answer (score 1):

Social networks are just another way to relate to others. Educating children into relationships is part of parent´s duties. You should use FB to experience its full capabilities and risks. Mainly you should educate your children to show respect to others, be it in a social network or any other social relation.